# ethereum geth with web3: privateToAccount not defined

Tags: ethereum

According to the doc for web3: http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html
I can use:

```
web3.eth.accounts.privateToAccount("0x78...");
```

I have this error:

```
TypeError: 'privateToAccount' is not a function
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

web3.eth.accounts is defined:

```
> web3.eth.accounts
["0x78...", "0xf3..."]
```

My question: why the function 'privateToAccount' is not defined ?

Also the result of web3.eth.accounts are private or public keys ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I just ran into the same issue and was able to reproduce this.

After some digging I noticed the linked docs are for version `1.0` which is an unreleased future version and [uncompleted milestone](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/projects/1).

Check your `web3.version`:

```
> web3.version
{ api: '0.18.4',
  node: [Getter],
  getNode: { [Function: get] request: [Function: bound ] },
  network: [Getter],
  getNetwork: { [Function: get] request: [Function: bound ] },
  ethereum: [Getter],
  getEthereum: { [Function: get] request: [Function: bound ] },
  whisper: [Getter],
  getWhisper: { [Function: get] request: [Function: bound ] } }
```

You will probably get `0.18.x` which does not support any `eth.accounts` sub-functions:

```
> web3.eth.accounts
web3.eth.accounts
```